# capybara webkit unable to load mailto url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2, capybara-webkit

I am testing my rails integration test with `capybara-webkit`, and my javascript needs to change the `location.href` to `mailto` url. It ends up with this error

```
Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
       Unable to load URL: mailto:chamnap@yoolk.com?subject=Inquiry to Cambodia%20Yellow%20Pages via Mail&body=To Cambodia%20Yellow%20Pages
```

How would I test in this case? I just need to make sure it has been to this url is enough. I don't need to do a real redirect in this case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use page.evaluate_script to register a dummy protocol handler for the mailto protocol.

[navigator.registerProtocolHandler](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler)

Comment: Do you have an example?